# not set inherited value during class instantiation

Tags: c++

I have this parent class for all my objects

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
/*
    Main parent class.
*/
class Object
{
protected:
    std::string className;
public:
    std::string getClassName() {
        return className;
    }
};
```

And I have inherited class

```
#pragma once
#include "object.cpp"

#include <iostream>

class Skill : public Object
{
private:
    Skill() {
        className = "skill";
    }
    std::string skillName;
public:
    Skill(std::string skillName) {
        this->skillName = skillName;
    }
    void useSkill() {
        std::cout<<"Skill is used";
    }
};
```

But when I try to get `className` in function `main` - it shows empty line.

```
int main()
{
    Skill *s = new Skill("Unique skill!");
    std::cout << "Attempt to retrieve skill " << s->getClassName(); // show only message Attempt to retrieve skill
}
```

What went wrong?

Comment: The two answers below are correct: you are never calling the `Skill()` constructor. Just one more thing: i noticed that you included `"object.cpp"` file. Why are you adding a .cpp file and not a .h file? You should only put class declarations (and then include) in headers (otherwise in more complocated cases you will come into severe issues, such as multiple variable definitions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that calling your single-argument constructor doesn't call your zero-argument constructor, so `className` is never set.

If you are using C++11, you can delegate to your default constructor to avoid the code duplication:

```
Skill(std::string skillName) : Skill(){
    this->skillName = skillName;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a single constructor with a default argument:

```
Skill(std::string skillName = "") : skillName(skillName){
    className = "skill"; //better to write an Object constructor to handle this
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the one argument constructor that you are calling from `main` leaves the `className` variable empty. Change the constructor definition to

```
Skill(std::string skillName) {
    className = "skill";
    this->skillName = skillName;
}
```

or call the other constructor from this (only works in `C++11`).

The better would be however using an initializer list

```
Skill(std::string skillName) : skillName(skillName) {
    className = "skill";
}
```